# Spring data JPA for bot

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I started making a bot. And would like to take advantage of spirng data JPA to make it easier. In the context of the spring, I'm not strong. I'm using a 3rd party bot library and it ran the bot like this:

```
public class VkBot extends LongPollBot {
     @Override
     public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
         //code
     }
     @Override
     public void onMessageNew(MessageNewEvent messageNewEvent) {
         //code
     }
      public static void main(String[] args) throws VkApiException {
         new BotsLongPoll(new VkBot()).run;
         /*BotsLongPoll is a class of library*/
     }
}
```

Now I have rewritten it so that it works like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class VkBot extends LongPollBot {
    PersonRepository personRepository;
    @Autowired
    public PersonRepository getPersonRepository() {
        return personRepository;
    }
    @Override
    public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
       //code
    }
    @Override
    public void onMessageNew(MessageNewEvent messageNewEvent) {
       personRepository.save(person)
       //code
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws VkApiException {

    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext annotationConfigApplicationContext = 
                     new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(JPAConfiguration.class);
    BotsLongPoll botsLongPollBean = annotationConfigApplicationContext.getBean(BotsLongPoll.class);
    botsLongPollBean.run();
}
```

Config:

```
@Configuration 
@EnableTransactionManagement 
@EnableJpaRepositories ("ru.voronavk.repositories")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan("ru.voronavk.entities")
@ComponentScan("ru.voronavk")
public class JPAConfiguration {
    @Bean
    VkBot vkBot(){
        return new VkBot();
    }
    @Bean
    BotsLongPoll botsLongPoll(){
        return new BotsLongPoll(vkBot());
    }
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUsername("equipment");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/botsdb");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("ru.voronavk.ru.voronavk.entities");

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }


    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");

        return properties;
    }
}
```

PersonRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
  
}
```

I get an error

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository' defined in ru.voronavk.repositories.PersonRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class ru.voronavk.entities.Person
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:934) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at ru.voronavk.VkBot.main(VkBot.java:302) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class ru.voronavk.entities.Person
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:582) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:75) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:233) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:182) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:165) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:324) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:322) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:328) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 15 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Tried also:

```
SpringBootApplication.run(BotsLongPoll.class)
```

Gave an NullPointer, bacause personRepository was null.

In which direction should I read?

Comment: The code provided does not compile, variable `person` in method `onMessageNew(...)` of class `VkBot` is undefined. --- `Not a managed entity` indicates that the annotation `@Entity` is missing on class `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Autowired annotation doesn't work like this. It's not an injection

```
@Autowired  
public PersonRepository getPersonRepository() {  
    return personRepository;  
}
```

You should read about different types of injection in Spring such as constructor, field, and setter injection, f.e. [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dependency-injection)

2. You should remove all these annotations from your JPAConfiguration, spring boot with data jpa starter does all what you need

```
@EnableTransactionManagement 
@EnableJpaRepositories ("ru.voronavk.repositories")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan("ru.voronavk.entities")
@ComponentScan("ru.voronavk")
```

Also with spring boot you don't need to create infrastructure beans like `DataSource`. All settings can be written in application.properties or other config files. About data jpa you can read [here](https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa)

3. Rewrite or create class with `@SpringBootApplication` annotation in root package of your project. It should look like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class VkBotConsoleApp implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private BotsLongPoll botsLongPoll;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(VkBotConsoleApp.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
       botsLongPoll.run();
    }
}
```